# how can I show two ion-col field inside ion-item section in IONIC 3

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I need to show two input field inside a **row** look like:

[image]

But when I use :

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label stacked> Phone Number</ion-label>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-input type="tel" placeholder="Area code"></ion-input>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-input type="tel" placeholder="Number"></ion-input>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-item>
```

But it not show any thing screen like:

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 9):

Please try to add ion-row before the ion-item. I hope this may help you. Thanks

```html
<ion-list>

  <ion-label stacked> Phone Number</ion-label>

    <ion-row>
    <ion-item col-6>
        <ion-input type="tel" placeholder="Area code"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item col-6>
        <ion-input type="tel" placeholder="Number"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    </ion-row>

</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `<ion-grid>` as shown below.

This is working [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-n2qhgt?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-4>
                <ion-label stacked> Phone Number</ion-label>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-4>
                <ion-input type="tel" placeholder="Area code"></ion-input>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-4>
                <ion-input type="tel" placeholder="Number"></ion-input>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't recommend creating a grid inside *every* item in the list ... can be really heavy to process.

But looking at your code, I see you only wanted to divid the row into two so each input will be next to each other..

So this simply worked for me (https://ionic-list-items-with-two-inputs-in-row.stackblitz.io/)

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-label stacked> Phone Number</ion-label>
    <ion-item>      
      <ion-input type="tel" placeholder="Area code"></ion-input>
      <ion-input type="tel" placeholder="Number"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `<ion-grid>` before `<ion-row>` as below, it worked for me inside the ion-item.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col>Lorem ipsum 1</ion-col>
            <ion-col size="shrink">lorem ipsum 2</ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-item>
```